# Splash screen is not being displayed

Tags: android

I have two classes as `Splash.java` and `Activity2.java`!! I have tried simple code for splash as:

```
public class Splash extends Activity 
    {
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.splash);
      Thread thread= new Thread()
    {
     @Override
   public void run() 
     {

     super.run();
     startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this,Trial.class));
     finish();

   }
  };
  thread.start();

 }
}
```

In my manifest I have given entry too. My code is running without error. Code of `R.layout.splash` is as:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >
<ImageView  
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/d"
android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Please reformat your code and.give more detail. Instead of new Thread try postDelayed(Runnable, it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
   setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Trial.class));
                finish();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
        }
    }).start();
```

xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/screen1">
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i have tried a number of approches and each time i am getting : Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front and after this my trial.class looks on the screen

Comment: this warning comes when the project is already running and you run again the project. You first close the project in simulator or device and then try to run.

Comment: Hii thanks for reply!!i already have done this even i close my whole project, clean that and again run still the problem is existing!!! i have given entry in manifest file too!!am i misssing someting yet........life cycle) after some miliseconds!!is it a fine approach

Answer (score 2):

```
    public class Splash extends Activity {
    RelativeLayout container;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
        container = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);



        Thread thread = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    sleep(3000);//sleeps for 3 second


                    Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this,Activity2.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 //   e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


                super.run();
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }



    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        // Checks the orientation of the screen
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setSize();
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            //Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setSize();
        }
    }

    private void setSize(){
        if(container!=null) {
            if (container.getChildCount() > 0) {
                container.getChildAt(0).setMinimumHeight(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() * 4 / 10);
            }
        }
    }


}

** your splash screeen layout **

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/shaded_rectangle"
    android:id="@+id/container">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/splas"/>
</RelativeLayout>


**manifest**



       <activity
            android:name=".collegeconnect.activity.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: after 5 yrs :)thnaks,

Comment: sorry i  just joined stack

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 4000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Handler().postDelayed

    (
    new Runnable()
    {
    @Override
    public void run ()
    {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
    }
    },SPLASH_TIME_OUT
    );
}
```

}